# ASP.NET Dynamic Data 4.0 - Search Results?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, entity-framework-4, asp.net-4.0

I have a ASP.NET (VB) Dynamic Data Project in ASP.NET 4.0. It works great - and offers filtering - but now I want to add searching to it. What is the best way to accomplish this in ASP.NET 4.0? Is there any built-in functionality for performing searches declaratively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the QueryExtender in ASP.NET 4.0.